# What does “stand with” mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

The following [article](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/11/20/trump-says-us-stands-with-saudi-arabia-despite-khashoggi-killing.html) fron CNBC states:

> Trump says US stands with Saudi Arabia despite journalist Khashoggi's killing.

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs defines the phrasal verb ***[stand with someone](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+with)*** as:

> to unite with someone, as in defense.
>
> - *Don't worry. I'll stand with you to the end. He stood with her and they faced the threat together.*

I could not find the definition of *stand with* on other online dictionaries, but the usage made by the CNBC appear to convey a different meaning from the one in the dictionary.

Are there other definitions and usages of “stand with?”

Is the expression used also in BrE?

Comment: Why do you think it means anything different than what you've already provided?

Answer (score 4):

It means to remain a loyal ally.   To stand (figuratively) shoulder to shoulder, confronting some form of opposition.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two meanings of "stand with".

1. To be/remain loyal to someone (Which is your case)
2. To physically remain with someone

Example:

> She stood with me around the campfire.

Source: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+with

Comment: Welcome to ELL, please can you source your answer? You can read about how to answer on the [ELL Help Pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help)